# Django TemplateSyntax Error with Sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to get Sorl-thumbnail running on my staging server, but I'm running into a TemplateSyntaxError which is throwing me since the app works fine on localhost.

The error is coming in at {% endthumbnail %}

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /home/
Invalid block tag: 'endthumbnail', expected 'endif'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% if picture.photo_medium %}
    <img src="{{AWS_URL}}{{picture.photo_medium}}" class="imagepage" width="400" height="300">
{% else %}
    {% if picture.photo_large|is_portrait %}
       <div class="portrait">
          {% thumbnail picture.photo_large "400" crop="center" as im %}
          <img src="{{AWS_URL}}{{ im }}">
       </div>
    {% else %}
       <div class="landscape">
          {% thumbnail picture.photo_large "400" crop="center" as im %}
          <img src="{{AWS_URL}}{{ im }}">
       </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And I am calling {% load thumbnail %} further up the page. Just in case someone wonders about that

Comment: I really don't see the problem, everything should work fine. Try experementing, by removing the {% if %} block, what will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think you need the `{% endthumbnail %}` tag.

Comment: According to docs (http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#template-examples) he does.

Comment: Well, that doesn't work for me either - I don't know how it can work on the local server at all. I've always used it without the endthumbnail tag - with it, I get the same error (always).

Comment: Bizarre - the solution was removing the endthumbnail, even though the docs use it.

Comment: @Herman One more question, I'm now getting Invalid filter:'is_portrait' and I'm wondering if you have yours setup differently than the docs when you use that too. I've posted the full code above. Thanks!

Comment: @Emile: Sorry, never used that option - however, I used `grep -r "portrait" *` in my sorl folder, and there's no mention of any `is_portrait` filter (the word `portrait` isn't anywhere to be seen) - so either it's a feature in a newer version of sorl, or it hasn't been implemented yet (or deprecated)!

Comment: Ultimately the bug was with the version of Sorl on the server. Updated 11.04

Comment: The answer above should be UNaccepted as the correct answer, as it's based on an old version of the lib. Jesse's answer below should be marked as accepted.

Comment: I am getting this error with sorl-thumbnails 11.12. If I remove the `{% endthumbnail %}`, then it works again.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that you have an older version of sorl-thumbnail installed on your localhost than is installed on your staging server. The endthumbnail tag was added relatively recently as part of a major rewrite.

If you find that you need to upgrade you may find the setting [THUMBNAIL-DEBUG](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/reference/settings.html#thumbnail-debug) helpful for tracking down other problems.

Comment: Yep - deleting all references to sorl on the host and then re-running "pip install sorl-thumbnail" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be with loading template tags.

I was doing `{% load thumbnail %}` in base html.
When I call below code in inherited html, got same error.

```
{% thumbnail service_type.pic.image "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
   <img .....>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

See this discussion [about loading template tags in base.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560222/is-it-possible-to-load-a-custom-template-tag-in-base-and-use-it-in-extented-temp)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem in using SORL Thumbnail in Mezzanine. Apparently Mezzanine loads it's own thumbnailer, so if you `{% load thumbnail mezzanine_tags %}`, mezzanine's `thumbnail` takes over from SORL's Thumbnail tag. However, if you reverse it `{% load mezzanine_tags thumbnail %}`, it works fine.

**Lesson Learned:** Make sure other libraries you're using aren't inadvertently taking over, and just to be safe maybe load thumbnail last.