# Is it possible to load a custom template tag in base and use it in extented templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I loaded a custom template tag `note_extras.py` in `base.html`.

#### base.html

```
<div id="wrap">
{% load note_extras %}    
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div><!--wrap-->
```

but it is not accessible at templates which is an extend of `base.html` ie::

#### home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
{% create_tagmenu request.user.pk %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

it is working fine if i load `note_extras` in `home.html` ie:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load note_extras %}
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django template language, you must load all needed template libraries in each of the templates.

I personally think it is a good idea because it makes templates more explicit (which is better than implicit). Ill give an example. Prior to Django 1.5, the default behavior for a `url` tag was to provide the view name in plaintext as well as all the needed parameters:

```
{% url path.to.view ... %}
```

There however was no way to provide the path to the view via a context variable:

```
{% with var='path.to.view' %}
    {% url var ... %}
{% endwith %}
```

To solve that, starting with 1.3, you could import the future version of the url tag (which became the default in 1.5) by doing:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url var ... %}
or
{% url 'path.to.view' ... %}
```

Now imagine that you would need to create a template which would extend from a base template which you did not create (e.g. one of django admin base templates). Then imagine that within the base template it would have `{% load url from future %}`. As a result, `{% url path.to.view ... %}` within your template would become invalid without any explicit explanation.

Of course this example does not matter anymore (starting with 1.5) however hopefully it illustrates a point that being explicit in templates is better than implicit which is why the currently implementation is the way it is.

Comment: I am also curious why it is not allowed to load all the tags in the base template. Perhaps this has changed after 3 years?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that a template tag is loaded in every template you want to do it in the **init** file of your app:

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins


add_to_builtins('my_app.templatetags.note_extras')
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, `add_to_builtins` has been deprecated but one could still load a tag for all of the templates in the project via `settings.TEMPLATES` - supported for Django 1.9 onwards as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719364/2447803