# How to use a custom template tag in base.html

Tags: django, django-templates

`.` is my project root, where `manage.py` resides. I have a base template at `./templates/base.html`. I have a custom template tag in `./app/templatetags/mytags.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.unread_tag
def get_unread(user):
    return user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

How do I make this tag usable for base.html, from which all app-level templates inherit.

Comment: Have you tried to put `{% load mytags %}` to the top of `base.html`?

Comment: {% load mytags %} gives me `'Library' object has no attribute 'unread_tag'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag definition is not correct. You need to use [`register.simple_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) decorator:

```
@register.simple_tag(name='unread')
def get_unread(user):
    return user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count()
```

Then, you need to [`load`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-load) the tag into the template:

```
{% load mytags %}
```

Then, you can use the tag in the template:

```
{% unread request.user %}
```

Comment: I am using as {% unread request.user %} I get the error that it takes two arguments and only 1 is provided. On removing request.user and restarting dev server the error remains the same.

Comment: thanks. On a different note, I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'notification_set'` which is being thrown on the line `return user.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count()`. On the shell, when I try `u.notification_set.filter(viewed=False).count()` where u is a User instance, I get the right answer. Would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question but things have changed since this was asked.
You can load a custom tag for ALL templates within the project in `settings.py` using the key `builtins` in `OPTIONS` of `settings.TEMPLATES`

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'builtins': [
            'app.templatetags.mytags',
        ],
    },
}]
```

You can read more about the options in the [Django doc - DjangoTemplates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) of built-in backends.

This option is supported from Django 1.9 onwards.