# Calling a function from another html template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

So I have a `base.html` template and a `review_result.html` template that extends the `base.html` template. The `base.html` template has a script tag with lots of function. I am going to move a function called `format` from a script tag in the `review_result.html` to the `base.html` file. How do I then call the `format` function in `review_result.html` from `base.html`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say your `base.html` _has_ a script tag? Generally speaking, _templates_ do not contain function code or tags. Available tags are either builtin or controlled by your site configuration or loaded in using `{% load %}` -- in any case, they are not _inside_ your templates, exactly. See [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/). Also, does this answer your question: [Is it possible to load a custom template tag in base and use it in extented templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20560222/5747944) ?

Comment: Hey there, welcomne to SO. It's a good question but could you edit your post and add any code that you have tried? It will definitely help any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Django templates just become static html (script tags included). If you extend from another template and it includes your JavaScript, then you should be able to call the function as though your `format` function were in your `review_result.html` template.