# Django template extension; django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag when trying to load i18n from a base template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a `base.html` template file for Django (4.1.2) as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {% load static %}
    {% load i18n %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      {% block title %}
        <title>My Title</title>
      {% endblock %}
   
     </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and an `index.html` page, at the same level in the `/templates` folder of my app, extending the base one, as:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>My Django project</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/admin">{% trans "Admin" %}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'foo' %}">{% trans "Foo" %}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

But when I browse the latter page, the server returns the following error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:
  Invalid block tag on line 6:
    'trans', expected 'endblock'.
    Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

But if I simply add `{% load i18n %}` at the second line of the `index.html`, the page loads fine.

What is wrong with the loading of the base template in the index.html page?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560222/is-it-possible-to-load-a-custom-template-tag-in-base-and-use-it-in-extented-temp) doesn't help as it doesn't differentiate the behaviour encountered here with the fact that loading, e.g. `{% load django_bootstrap5 %}` in `base.html` is working very well through *all* child pages without having to ever specify it again in those pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to load a custom template tag in base and use it in extented templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560222/is-it-possible-to-load-a-custom-template-tag-in-base-and-use-it-in-extented-temp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to globally enable `i18n` in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
        'builtins': ['django.templatetags.i18n'], # <---- add this line
    },
]
```

Then, apparently, you no more need to load this template tag in every html template. It is not even necessary in `base.html` anymore.

More on templates built-in backends: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django

And on writing {% load i18n %} only once: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1193

Inspired by: [Load a Django template tag library for all views by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

you must always load any tag library in each page if you want to use it.Even if the you have already load it in parent page.

Comment: Hmm, okay, but then how do you explain that loading, e.g. `{% load django_bootstrap5 %}` in `base.html` is working very well throughout all child pages without having to ever specify it again?

Comment: @s.k to answer that do you actually use "django_bootstrap5" in all of your child templates?

Comment: No, I do not. But I actually see layout changes in all pages extending the base.html template. And `{% load django_bootstrap5 %}` is only specified once; in this base.html template. But for `i18n` it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Comment: @s.k Well the layout changes will happen in all the templates because it's CSS...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).